# Read Windows 7 Registry c#

Tags: c#

Need to obtain following path from the registry:

%userprofile%

Comment: That's an environment variable. Why do you want to retrieve it from the registry?

Answer (score 5):

In C#, you can use this:

`Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)`

to load up the path to the current user's profile.